# executing java -jar via classpath vs in the jar file dir

Tags: java, jar, classpath

After having used NetBeans to create a Java program call it Addition and then having successfully cleaned and built an Executable Jar File in a folder c:\Users\Ben\Doc\NetBeansProjects\Addition\dist

WHY is it that when executing, from command prompt, 
c:\Users\Ben Java -Jar -cp "c:\Users\Ben\Doc\NetBeansProjects\Addition\dist" Addition.jar 
it does NOT work (i get 'unable to access jarfile Addition.jar)
BUT if i use cd to change my current dir to c:\Users\Ben\Doc\NetBeansProjects\Addition\dist and THEN run 'java -jar Addition.jar' from there, the Addition program runs fine

Answer (score 2):

The -classpath argument is ignored when you use the -jar option. See the documentation.

Comment: wow, can you elaborate?  So, when you're running a JAR, you can't add another JAR to the classpath!?

Comment: @Thufir That's what I said, and it's what the documentation says too. Any further elaboration required shoudl be sought there.

Comment: No problem, documentation at:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html   you can sort of do it.

Comment: @Thufir You can do it by modifying the manifest. No 'sort of' about that. But it isn't what the OP asked about.

Answer (score 1):

because java doesn't look in classpath to launch jar file for this command it needs file as input

so if you set the directory where your jar file is placed and try to execute java -jar command and expect it to pick up jar from that directory because it is in classpath it is not valid

you can give full path to jar like from any directory

```
java -jar c:\Users\Ben\Doc\NetBeansProjects\Addition\dist\Addition.jar
```

Comment: Of course Java uses the CLASSPATH to locate JAR files. That's what CLASSPATH is for. However it doesn't do it *in this case,* for another reason.

Comment: @EJP ofcourse yes, didn't think it looked that way, updated, you may revert your downvote :)

Comment: @EJP thanks for your explanation. i just tried to run java -jar c:\Users\Ben\Doc\NetBeansProjects\Addition\dist\Addition.jar in CMD. but it didint work. care to speculate the reason? thank you

Comment: @2ndhalfChessboard Not unless you provide more information. 'Didn't work' isn't sufficient.