# how do I execute a JAR and also add another JAR to the classpath?

Tags: java, jar, classpath, command-line-interface, package

How do I execute `HelloClient.jar` with `openejb-client` on the classpath?

```
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ java -cp -jar NetBeansProjects/HelloClient/dist/HelloClient.jar; apache-openejb-4.7.1/lib/openejb-client-4.7.1.jar org.acme.HelloClient
Error: Could not find or load main class NetBeansProjects.HelloClient.dist.HelloClient.jar
apache-openejb-4.7.1/lib/openejb-client-4.7.1.jar: line 1: $'PK\003\004': command not found
apache-openejb-4.7.1/lib/openejb-client-4.7.1.jar: line 2: $'\250m,E': command not found
apache-openejb-4.7.1/lib/openejb-client-4.7.1.jar: line 3: $'\b\247m,Ey\037\030': command not found
apache-openejb-4.7.1/lib/openejb-client-4.7.1.jar: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
apache-openejb-4.7.1/lib/openejb-client-4.7.1.jar: line 4: `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF�V]S�0}�L�C�gq�� ,;�#����NhC��I7I���MZ)���6�����s��T���Q�|o�Τ2�#��HBC$U�IF�%�2����q�gJ�7���:������<;���'�:C|�n;�����Q���Kq-il�`���W�N�X����:�x�SU'
thufir@doge:~$
```

Do I have to make the jar on the classpath executable?

see also:

http://openejb.apache.org/hello-world.html

Comment: might not be possible:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/24297050/262852

Comment: You are feeding your classpath into the `-jar` option. Look here and see if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/945962/java-problem-running-a-jar-file-in-command-line

Comment: @Matze I believe that's the solution, to use : for linux and `classpath` instead of `cp` and use . for current directory (if I understand the syntax of the command!)

Answer (score -1):

per Matz:

```
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ java -classpath .:NetBeansProjects/HelloClient/dist/HelloClient.jar:apache-openejb-4.7.1/lib/openejb-client-4.7.1.jar org.acme.HelloClient
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ejb/EJBHome
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
    at com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12.loadClass(VersionHelper12.java:72)
    at com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12.loadClass(VersionHelper12.java:61)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:671)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:307)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:242)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:216)
    at org.acme.HelloClient.main(HelloClient.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ejb.EJBHome
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 9 more
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$
```